# Hide navigation menu items unless auto-user

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a navigation menu at the bottom. The first two tabs are authorization and settings). Is it possible to do so if I am not authorized (or I understand authorized through the global variable global.nameUser, if it is not zero then I am authorized) so that all other menu items are not visible. And what was visible only the first two points.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/Status.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/Seals_List.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/auth_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/Setting_glob.dart';
import 'package:sentry_flutter/sentry_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/add_seals/JsonAddSeals.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/user_page/page.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await SentryFlutter.init(
        (options) => options.dsn = 'https://',
    appRunner: () => runApp(Main_Page()),
  );

}



class Main_Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home: new LoginPage());
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Ви впевнині?'),
        content: new Text('Ви хочете вийти з додатку'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            child: Text("Ні"),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16),
          new GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
            child: Text("Так"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ) ??
        false;
  }


  int _pageIndex = 0;
  PageController _pageController;

  List<Widget> tabPages = [
    Login(),
    Setting(),
    AppS(),
    Status_Obj(),
    Status_seals(),
    JsonParseAddSeals(),
  ];

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _pageIndex);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
        child: new Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
              bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                showSelectedLabels: true,   // <-- HERE
                showUnselectedLabels: true, // <-- AND
                currentIndex: _pageIndex,
                onTap: onTabTapped,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem( icon: Icon(Icons.admin_panel_settings_outlined), title: Text(" Вхід"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text("Налаштування"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin), title: Text("Користувач"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("Пломбування"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code), title: Text("Пломби"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add_outlined), title: Text("Акт приймання"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),

                ],

              ),
            body: PageView(
              children: tabPages,
              onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
              controller: _pageController,
            ),
          ),
    );



  }
  void onPageChanged(int page) {
    setState(() {
      this._pageIndex = page;
    });
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    this._pageController.animateToPage(index,duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),curve: Curves.easeInOut);
  }
}
```

Authorization page:
[image]

Menu items that should be visible if the user is not authorized:[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using an if statement in the widget tree. If the user is auth then show every icons, otherwise only show the two firsts:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/Seals_List.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/Setting_glob.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/Status.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/auth_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/add_seals/JsonAddSeals.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_seals/model/user_page/page.dart';
import 'package:sentry_flutter/sentry_flutter.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  await SentryFlutter.init(
    (options) => options.dsn = 'bdівсвім',
    appRunner: () => runApp(Main_Page()),
  );
}

class Main_Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(home: new LoginPage());
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  Future<bool> _onBackPressed() {
    return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Ви впевнині?'),
            content: new Text('Ви хочете вийти з додатку'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                child: Text("Ні"),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              new GestureDetector(
                onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                child: Text("Так"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ) ??
        false;
  }

  int _pageIndex = 0;
  PageController _pageController;

  List<Widget> tabPages = [
    Login(),
    Setting(),
    AppS(),
    Status_Obj(),
    Status_seals(),
    JsonParseAddSeals(),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _pageIndex);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
      child: new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        bottomNavigationBar: (global.nameUser != 0)
            ? BottomNavigationBar(
                showSelectedLabels: true,
                // <-- HERE
                showUnselectedLabels: true,
                // <-- AND
                currentIndex: _pageIndex,
                onTap: onTabTapped,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.admin_panel_settings_outlined),
                      title: Text(" Вхід"),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                      title: Text("Налаштування"),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin),
                      title: Text("Користувач"),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                      title: Text("Пломбування"),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code),
                      title: Text("Пломби"),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add_outlined),
                      title: Text("Акт приймання"),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                ],
              )
            : BottomNavigationBar(
                showSelectedLabels: true,
                // <-- HERE
                showUnselectedLabels: true,
                // <-- AND
                currentIndex: _pageIndex,
                onTap: onTabTapped,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.admin_panel_settings_outlined),
                      title: Text(" Вхід"),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                      title: Text("Налаштування"),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                ],
              ),
        body: PageView(
          children: tabPages,
          onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
          controller: _pageController,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onPageChanged(int page) {
    setState(() {
      this._pageIndex = page;
    });
  }

  void onTabTapped(int index) {
    this
        ._pageController
        .animateToPage(index, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeInOut);
  }
}
```

Comment: one nuance, after auto-authorization I go to the desired page, but the menu items do not appear at the bottom, there is only a menu item settings. And in order for the other menu items to appear, I have to go to the settings tab and only after that everything appears)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an if statement with a spread operator to hide/display whatever options you want.

```
  items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem( icon: Icon(Icons.admin_panel_settings_outlined), title: Text(" Вхід"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), title: Text("Налаштування"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
             if(userAllowedToSeeOtherOptions) ...[
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin), title: Text("Користувач"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("Пломбування"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code), title: Text("Пломби"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
                  new BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add_outlined), title: Text("Акт приймання"),backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue),
             ]
                ],
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I did according to your example, but there was a problem. The problem is that after logging in, I go to the desired page and I do not see all the navigation menu icons. To make them appear, I need to click on one of the available icons (only 2 icons are available for authorization) and only then the navigation menu will be updated and everything will be as it should be. All 6 icons will be visible!